# Android Studio application is not working. I believe the problem is in the sendAndRequestResponse() method

Tags: android, android-studio

I am creating a simple application in Android Studio for managing a device connected via wifi using the Volley library.

The app must do this: when you click on the On button the device must turn on and consequently show the image of a light bulb on, while when I click on the Off button the device must turn off and show the image of a light bulb off on the screen . In Postman the interaction with the device works correctly.

When I start the app and click on the on/off button nothing happens, that is, it always shows me an image of an unlit light bulb. The logcat gives me no errors.
By debugging I notice that when the sendAndRequestResponse() method is executed it does not enter the onResponse method but jumps directly to the setRetryPolicy method.
Can you kindly help me?

These are the values of the variables while debugging:
[Values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8hpg.png)

MainActivity.java

```js
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import java.text.BreakIterator;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getName();
    SwitchCompat switchButton;
    LinearLayout imageViewLight;
    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
    TextView buttonState;
    private StringRequest mStringRequest;
    private String url = "https://192.168.130.15:8081/zeroconf/switch";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        switchButton=findViewById(R.id.switchButton);
        imageViewLight=findViewById(R.id.linearL);
        TextView buttonState;
        buttonState = findViewById(R.id.buttonState);

        switchButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                sendAndRequestResponse();                
            }
        });
    }

    private void sendAndRequestResponse() {
        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        mStringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                TextView myTextView;
                if (switchButton.isChecked()) {
                    imageViewLight.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.light__02);
                    buttonState.setText("State : ON");
                } else {
                    imageViewLight.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.light__01);
                    buttonState.setText("State : OFF");
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                Log.i(TAG,"Error :" + error.toString());
            }
        });
        
        mStringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new RetryPolicy() {
            @Override
            public int getCurrentTimeout() {
                return 50000;
            }

            @Override
            public int getCurrentRetryCount() {
                return 50000;
            }

            @Override
            public void retry(VolleyError error) throws VolleyError {

            }
        });

        mRequestQueue.add(mStringRequest);  

    }
}
```

Comment: you are able to access that IP address on your mobile device?

Comment: that is? What do you mean? because I tried to create the hotspot with the mobile device and I am able to interact with the device

Comment: are you able to `https://192.168.137.139:8081/zeroconf/switch` hit this endpoint in your mobile device browser?

Comment: no I can't log in to that site. I tried but it says unable to reach the site.
Yet with Postman it works

Comment: Is this your machine ip where you hosted the server?

Comment: that ip is the address of the device connected with my machine that allows me to interact with it. In fact, if I put that URL on Postman I can interact easily

Comment: Your mobile device on which you installed the app and trying to call this endpoint is on same network?

Comment: the device on which the app is installed is the android studio emulator. But I do nothing on this emulator, in the sense that I do everything from the PC. I activate the mobile hotspot from the pc and not from the emulator. Is this a problem? I do not know if I was clear.

Comment: Just wanted to you try one thing if that works I can provide you with an explanation. can you please change the URL to `"http://10.0.2.2:8081/zeroconf/switch"` and test on emulator and let me know if that works

Comment: do I have to try this URL in the browser?

Comment: no in your code

Comment: tried, only nothing happens. The same thing happens with the previous URL

Comment: And the same thing is working on a real device in same network right ?

Comment: yes exactly, always on the same network

Comment: so you only have an issue on emulator but not in real mobile device reason is emulator is not in the same network if you see the IP in your emulator it might be something like 10.0.X.X but your laptop is in 192.168.x.x hence your emulator cannot access it as it is, that is also the reason you are not able to hit your 192.168.x.x URL in emulator browser.

Comment: how can i see the ip of my emulator? so I do a check

Comment: click on the wifi tab -> Select `AndroidWifi` which is your wifi name in emulator -> Click Advance -> scroll to see IP Address

Comment: i just checked. It is exactly as you say. So what am I supposed to do now?

Comment: is your code is just hosted on LAN or you can access it from a computer on a different network using a public IP, that means your friend can access it at his place using your public IP?

Comment: about this I don't know how to answer you, because this thing was not foreseen. How can I see this thing? However I just want it to be on LAN

Comment: @dinkar_kumar what do you suggest me to do?